# Method not alowed - Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException The POST method is not supported

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to do a course in Laravel and I try to set up a simple CRUD method and I got stuck on the Create.  I have an error in Laravel and I do not understand how to solve it, I tried to clear route-cache but does not work. I watched some answers with this error but i am not sure do they match as I am using the post method in web file.
[Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH9Yp.png)

Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Todo;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TodosControler extends Controller
{





public function index() 
{
    return view('todos.index')->with('todos', Todo::all());
}

//za pojedine 
public function show($todoId)
{
    //dd($todoId); //diedump isto kao die u PHPu

     // $todo = Todo::find($todoId);  onda ovo kad slozimo samo stavimo u return
     return view('todos.show')->with('todo', Todo::find($todoId));
}

public function create()
{
    return view('todos.create');
}

public function store()
{
  $data = request()->all();
  $todo = new Todo();
  $todo->name = $data['name'];
  $todo->description = $data['description'];
  $todo->completed = false;
  $todo->save();
  return redirect('/todos');
}


}
```

web file

```
use App\Http\Controllers\AboutController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('todos' , 'TodosControler@index');

Route::get('todos/{todo}' , 'TodosControler@show');

Route::get('new-todos' , 'TodosControler@create');

Route::post('store-todos' , 'TodosControler@store');
```

Form

```
    <form action="/store-todos" method="POST">
             @csrf
      <div class="form-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="description" cols="5" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="description"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group text-center">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create todo</button>
      </div>


  </form>
```

Comment: `php artisan cache:clear`

`php artisan route:cache` `php artisan optimize` have you tried ?

Comment: Have you run command `composer install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here is mistake `Route::get('new-todos' , 'TodosControler@create')`. 
Maybe you need `Route::post('new-todos' , 'TodosControler@create')`

Hope it's help.

Comment: Apparently, as I test it again from the start and this mistake was not the problem, I did the undo and change it back. Then it worked as if nothing happened. I presume that it was a cache problem.